# input an RSS feed and it will collect articles, save and display those items locally for offline access

Tags: offline, rss

This is for extemporaneous speaking, a forensics event. Basically, I've been hacking together a solution by:

1. Getting the RSS feed
2. Getting the full text RSS feed
3. Feeding *that* RSS feed into IFTTT
4. IFTTT -> Evernote
5. Evernote offline sync

So far it's been.... alright. They really great thing was Evernote's searching abilities. But Evernote doesn't give me enough space anymore, and the IFTTT actions get turned off about a week into my new Evernote month. Is there a program- not necessarily a free one- that can replicate what I've done here?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but did you take a look at the [ownCloud Newsreader](https://github.com/owncloud/news)? That seems to do 1+2, at which state you've got the articles into your (local) database. Use either the WebIf, or one of the supporting apps (which exist at least on Android) to sync with.